# Need old Sheridan Data Widget Controls 3.13

Tags: vb6

I am trying to find Sheridan Controls 3.13 for a old VB6 project I need to open and convert. I used to have a registered version but I can't find where I archived them. Is there anyone who can provide me a copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That control is not free, so there is no legal way to get a free version. Sorry!

If the worst comes to the worst, you could buy it again. For instance it seems to be [£319 (UK pounds) from Component Source](https://www.componentsource.com/product/data-widgets/prices) at the time of typing.

If you have a receipt from when you originally purchased the control, the vendor might supply it to you again free of charge. Worth a try.

Comment: Assuming the OP genuinely owns a license to the controls, would it matter what the source of the files was? I suppose malware would be a concern if downloading from a random source.

Comment: I eventual convinced infragistics to send it to me. They were a bit reluctant but they found my old record when I purchased them about 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually convinced infragistics to send it to me. They were a bit reluctant but they found my old record when I purchased them about 20 years ago.